# I can not connect to a WebSocket build on NestJS WebSocket Gateway

Tags: websocket, nestjs

The light WebSocket example has been implemented according to the [NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways) and [an example on github](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/02-gateways)

According to the logs I see that the gateway has been loaded, registered, and subscribed.

```bash
[Nest] 113767  - 10/31/2023, 9:43:49 PM     LOG [WebSocketsController] MigrationGateway subscribed to the "message" message
```

The application is running on port 3000

```bash
[Nest] 113767  - 10/31/2023, 9:43:49 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started
Application is running on: http://[::1]:3000
```

The gateway is registered by the decorator without extra options

```js
@WebSocketGateway()
export class MigrationGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
```

I connect to the socket from the console and receive.

```js
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
```

```bash
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed:
```

I also tried from bash.

```bash
wscat -c ws://localhost:3000
error: socket hang up
```

I do not see any issue in the server log. It is like it needs to be set up.

I have not checked the socket.io client.

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```

But I do not think this is a problem.

Suggest to me where to look into the issue.

Regards.

Comment: `http://[::1]:3000` is an IPv6 address.  Are you intentionally forcing IPv6?  Does it work if you use the IPv6 address when you connect?

Comment: But it is still localhost. I hope the network adapter resolves it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to use `ws` with NestJS you need to make use of the [`WsAdapter`](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/adapter#ws-library) from `@nestjs/platform-ws`. By default, and just following the docs, Nest uses the `SocketIoAdapter` from `@nestjs/platform-socket.io` which needs to be connected to using the `socket.io-client` package at `http://localhost:3000` instead of `ws://localhost:3000`